# How to call an async API fully synchronously within a loop in Dart?

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await, synchronization

How to call an async API fully synchronously within a loop in Dart?

For example, if I have

```
for(...) {
  await doSomethingLongAsync();
}
```

as I understand, doSomethingLongAsync() will be invoked sequentionally but asynchronously on each iteration of the loop, i.e. each subsequent iteration of the loop will asynchronously call doSomethingLongAsync() even before the call of the previous iteration completes.

What I need is to make sure that a subsequent iteration of the loop does not invoke doSomethingLongAsync() until the previous iteration's invokation of the same function fully completes.

Comment: "i.e. each subsequent iteration of the loop will asynchronously call doSomethingLongAsync() even before the call of the previous iteration completes." That understanding is wrong. `await` means that that code will not resume execution until `doSomethingLongAsync` completes.

Comment: However, be aware that while you're waiting for each call of `doSomethingLongAsync` to complete, something could trigger the code with the loop *again*, which would create a separate set of calls to `doSomethingLongAsync`.  That would be a different problem, though.

Comment: @jamesdlin, thanks! Yes, that is maybe the case - double entry of the loop.

Comment: @jamesdlin, yes, it does look like I am getting multiple entries into the loop at the same time, invoked in response to a stream events. Is there a way in Dart to have something like a mutex/critical-section?

Comment: @AKornich are all of these events originating from a single `Stream` object? If so, I would consider either processing the events using `asyncMap` (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html) or processing the events using `await for` (https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#receiving-stream-events). Either one should allow you to process the stream events sequentially.

Comment: @AKornich code in a Dart isolate is single-threaded, so you don't need mutexes or special atomic operations to prevent unwanted re-entrancy; you can just set a boolean flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as I understand, doSomethingLongAsync() will be invoked sequentionally but asynchronously on each iteration of the loop, i.e. each subsequent iteration of the loop will asynchronously call doSomethingLongAsync() even before the call of the previous iteration completes.

That is not correct, when you `await`, it will not move on (within the context of the `async` function) until the `Future` being awaited completes.

> What I need is to make sure that a subsequent iteration of the loop does not invoke doSomethingLongAsync() until the previous iteration's invokation of the same function fully completes.

The code you have written already does this.

To illustrate, try running this code:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    print('start loop $i');
    await doSomethingLongAsync(i);
    print('end loop $i\n');
  }
}

Future<void> doSomethingLongAsync(int i) async {
  print('start doSomethingLongAsync $i');
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  print('end doSomethingLongAsync $i');
}
```

You will see that it does not continue to the next iteration of the loop until the `Future` being awaited is complete.